# Printing children of a preference node

Tags: java, oracle, registry

I want to print the children of a preference node. I've wrote the following code:

```
private void printOracleDefaults() {
    Preferences p = Preferences.userRoot();
    p = p.node("/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/ORACLE");
    try {
       for(String s : p.childrenNames())
          System.out.println(s);
    } catch (BackingStoreException e) {
       //bla bla..
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The method above doesn't print anything, although ORACLE has children:

[image: Children of ORACLE]

What I'm doing wrong or misunderstanding?

**UPDATE:**

I wrote `p = p.node("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE");`

instead of

`p = p.node("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/ORACLE");`

and when I printed the childrens of `p` I got: `ORACLE`! How is it possible? What about all other childrens? (There are.. I saw them through the Registry Editor)

Looks like it was storing the previous values from the previous runs that were attached next to `/SOFTWARE`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `Preferences.systemRoot()` instead of `Preferences.userRoot()` here. The latter maps to HKEY_CURRENT_USER.

With Windows, the path should be `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE` and then you escape it inside the String like `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\ORACLE`.

Note: I've not tried this myself.

Comment: No, I typed: `p = p.node("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\ORACLE");`

Comment: I'm thinking if you should use `Preferences.systemRoot()` instead of `Preferences.userRoot()` here. The latter maps to HKEY_CURRENT_USER

Comment: I'm clueless at this point as I don't have access to a windows machine to test/debug further.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22379/discussion-between-swapnil-and-maroun-maroun)