# How to get subkeys list of a given key

Tags: java, registry

I want to have a list that contains all the **subkeys** of a given **key**:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\  -> I want to have a list of all the subkeys of ORACLE

I wrote this code but it doesn't work:

```
   Preferences p = Preferences.userRoot();
   p = p.node("/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/ORACLE");
   try {
      for(String s : p.childrenNames())
         System.out.println(s);
   } catch (BackingStoreException e) {
      //bla bla..
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

***Link to my previous less clear question:*** [Printing children of a preference node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212971/printing-children-of-a-preference-node)

Comment: You can also provide a link to the other question you asked (since it's related).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution:

I'll invoke this command from the `cmd`: (Via `Java`)

> reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_HOST\SOFTWARE\ORACLE"

Which will return the `subkeys` of `ORACLE` and then I'll manipulate the output in order to get exactly what I want.